# MPI Gathering arrays of strings

Tags: c++, string, mpi

I'm trying to merge a collection of dictionaries into the root process. Here's a short example:

```cpp
#define MAX_CF_LENGTH 55

    map<string, int> dict;

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        dict = {
            {"Accelerator Defective", 33},
            {"Aggressive Driving/Road Rage", 27},
            {"Alcohol Involvement", 19},
            {"Animals Action", 30}};
    }
    if (rank == 1)
    {
        dict = {
            {"Driver Inexperience", 6},
            {"Driverless/Runaway Vehicle", 46},
            {"Drugs (Illegal)", 38},
            {"Failure to Keep Right", 24}};
    }
    if (rank == 2)
    {
        dict = {
            {"Lost Consciousness", 1},
            {"Obstruction/Debris", 8},
            {"Other Electronic Device", 25},
            {"Other Lighting Defects", 43},
            {"Other Vehicular", 7}};
    }

    Scatterer scatterer(rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_workers);
    scatterer.gatherDictionary(dict, MAX_CF_LENGTH);
```

The idea inside `gatherDictionary()` is to put every key in a `char` array at each process (duplicates are allowed). After that, gathering all keys into the root and creating the final (merged) dictionary before broadcasting it. Here's the code:

```cpp
void Scatterer::gatherDictionary(map<string,int> &dict, int maxKeyLength)
{
    // Calculate destination dictionary size
    int numKeys = dict.size();
    int totalLength = numKeys * maxKeyLength;
    int finalNumKeys = 0;
    MPI_Reduce(&numKeys, &finalNumKeys, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);

    // Computing number of elements that are received from each process
    int *recvcounts = NULL;
    if (rank == 0)
        recvcounts = new int[num_workers];

    MPI_Gather(&totalLength, 1, MPI_INT, recvcounts, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);

    // Computing displacement relative to recvbuf at which to place the incoming data from each process
    int *displs = NULL;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        displs = new int[num_workers];

        displs[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num_workers; i++)
            displs[i] = displs[i - 1] + recvcounts[i - 1] + 1;
    }

    char(*dictKeys)[maxKeyLength];
    char(*finalDictKeys)[maxKeyLength];
    dictKeys = (char(*)[maxKeyLength])malloc(numKeys * sizeof(*dictKeys));
    if (rank == 0)
        finalDictKeys = (char(*)[maxKeyLength])malloc(finalNumKeys * sizeof(*finalDictKeys));

    // Collect keys for each process
    int i = 0;
    for (auto pair : dict)
    {
        strncpy(dictKeys[i], pair.first.c_str(), maxKeyLength);
        i++;
    }

    MPI_Gatherv(dictKeys, totalLength, MPI_CHAR, finalDictKeys, recvcounts, displs, MPI_CHAR, 0, comm);

    // Create new dictionary and distribute it to all processes
    dict.clear();
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < finalNumKeys; i++)
            dict[finalDictKeys[i]] = dict.size();
    }

    delete[] dictKeys;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        delete[] finalDictKeys;
        delete[] recvcounts;
        delete[] displs;
    }

    broadcastDictionary(dict, maxKeyLength);
}
```

I'm sure of `broadcastDicitonary()` correctness as I've already tested it. Debugging into the gathering function I'm getting the following partial results:

```
Recvcounts:
220
220
275

Displacements:
0
221
442

FinalDictKeys:
Rank:0 Accelerator Defective
Rank:0 Aggressive Driving/Road Rage
Rank:0 Alcohol Involvement
Rank:0 Animals Action
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0 
Rank:0
```

Since only root data is being collected I'm wondering if this has something to do with the characters allocation even if it should be contiguous. I don't think this is related to a missing null character at the end since there's already a lot of padding for each string/key.
Thanks in advance for pointing out any missings or improvements and please comment if you need any extra infos.

If you wish to test it yourself I've put in a one-file only the code all together, it is compile&run ready (of course this works with 3 mpi processes). [Code Here](https://pastebin.com/aCTw0dCD)

Comment: It's stated at the first row but I've added it to the parameter list for clarity. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `displs[i] = displs[i - 1] + recvcounts[i - 1] + 1;` Why `+1` at the end?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The code has a lot of dependencies so I've put only the essentials all together in one paste. Added the link.

Comment: @DanielLangr Since the count is for instance 220, I thought that the next displacements should have started at 221 etc. Didn't consider the fact that I'm actually starting from 0... That's quite embarassing since a ```+1``` changed everything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OT: Isn't _gather_ followed by _broadcast_ effectively _allgather_ (`MPI_Allgatherv` in your case)? Which may be more optimized than sending everything over root.

Comment: So, does it solve the problem? I wasn't sure if there is not another problem as well, therefore, I just posted it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Yes Daniel, it all worked out. As for the OT, you're absolutely right but since I've had to add a broadcasting only feature for different computations I thought it would have been cleaner to make every function do exactly what is meant to do. I don't know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yes, it makes. If it is not a performance-critical gather-broadcast combination, then, you are likely ok. If the code should run on large supercomputers with tens or hundreds of thousands of MPI processes, than, I would optionally run `MPI_Gatherv` or `MPI_Allgatherv` according to the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
displs[i] = displs[i - 1] + recvcounts[i - 1] + 1;
```

That `+ 1` at the end is superfluous. Change it to:

```
displs[i] = displs[i - 1] + recvcounts[i - 1];
```